reattaching front camera housing
My daughter just bought a 2019 Ford Escape SE 1.4 turbo. 47,000 mi.
Upon inspecting the faulty rain sense sensor, I noticed that the previous owner improperly installed the plastic housing that contains this sensor and the front camera. The housing was separated from the windshield by about 1\2" on one side by dried glue. I was able to remove the plastic housing. What I would like to know is the proper type of glue to use to reattach. The side that attaches to the window has nubs that keep the housing about 1\16th" off the window, so a liquid glue will not work. It will need heavy duty 2 sided pads or some glue with a thick consistency. Does anyone know the proper product to use?

Does this need to be removable, or permanently fixed?

I've already tried something but your thought s are still appreciated because I may be redoing it. It will be permanent.

Not knowing what was used in by the OEM, there is rearview mirror adhesive. Personally, I think something which is an epoxy would work best. I read on the internet people have also had good luck with cyanoacrylate adhesives (otherwise known as "Superglue").

I also don't know what OEM was as it was reattached by someone else at least once. There are three pads that indicate there was two sided tape applied, but they seem way too small to hold. Someone used a thick type of black adhesive which held very good but they didn't hold the housing to the windshield long enough so one side separated from the windshield and then dried. Rearview mirror adhesive or super glue will not work because there is a 1\8" gap from the windshield and bracket created by nubs sticking out from bracket.

It may be a learning experience, but I went with the 2 sided tape. She's not a paying customer, so it really doesn't hurt to experiment. If it doesn't hold I'll do something different. Worst case scenario is it falls off. One other unfortunate thing is that I don't think I got it positioned perfectly. I don't think it will affect the lane assist though, but if it does I will do it again after I know it holds. I also confirmed that the rain assist sensor is bad.
